# Camera2: What does the handler in createCaptureSession(List, CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback, Handler) mean?

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-handler

I am reading about android's `camera2` api and I can't understand what the handler variable in the following request mean?

```
cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(List, CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback, Handler)
```

I was going through the camera2basic code from [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) class and they have put the handler value as null when making the above call. However in other places such as in `setRepeatingRequest` call or `imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener`call they use the `backgroundHandler` that they created.

From what I understood the `backgroundThread` (and the handler) created is  the one where all the came stuff happens i.e the camera session and callbacks. Then why does the `cameraDevice.createCaptureSession` isn't supplied this value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Handler: The handler on which the callback should be invoked, or null to use the current thread's looper.

In the camera2basic sample, [using](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L692) the current (Main) looper for preview CameraCaptureSession is good enough, because its callback is not involved in expensive tasks, and is called only once. The other callbacks that use backgroundThread, must be scheduled off the Main (UI) thread.